# find line number in an unstructured file in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, line-numbers

Hi guys I am parsing an unstructured file for some key words but i can't seem to easily find the line number of what the results I am getiing

```
val filePath:String = "myfile"
val myfile = sc.textFile(filePath);
var ora_temp = myfile.filter(line => line.contains("MyPattern")).collect
ora_temp.length
```

However, I not only want to find the lines that contains MyPatterns but I want more like a tupple (Mypattern line, line number)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you can do the following : myfile.zipWithIndex.filter(line => line._1.contains("MyPattern")).collect

Comment: Why not post this as an answer?

Comment: Because I was in the tramway and my connection was bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ZipWithIndex as eliasah pointed out in a comment (with probably the most succinct way to do this using the direct tuple accessor syntax), or like so using pattern matching in the filter:

```
val matchingLineAndLineNumberTuples = sc.textFile("myfile").zipWithIndex().filter({
  case (line, lineNumber) => line.contains("MyPattern")
}).collect
```